# Roadmap for careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

As of now you can purchase an account on careers.stackoverflow.com but once you've filled out your CV, set your CV's visibility and verified your email you get....???

Considering the clock is ticking on your purchase can we get and official roadmap or at date for when the service will be live -- other then 6 to 8 week :-)

Or can the active time period of the CV be reset to 1 or 3 years (depending on the purchased account lifetime) at the end of the beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the email we sent to all paid CV users, we will notify you of any significant new features.

We do plan to email paid users when major new features are released to http://careers.stackoverflow.com; this would happen once every month at most.

And, the public CVs are now live (sorry for the delay).

Answer (score 1):

AT least one thing we seem to know from the [podcast 70 shownotes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/podcast-70/):

> As a part of careers, we’re planning
> to roll out free, public CVs with
> user-selectable “vanity” URLs in a
> week or two. In retrospect, we should
> have done this from day one, as it
> compliments the public record of your
> Q&A on Stack Overflow. As Joel notes,
> the best way to control your online
> presence is to fill it yourself with
> all the cool stuff you’ve been doing!
> Don’t let others tell the story of you
> when you can tell it yourself.

Within the podcast it was narrowed down to "end of October 23."

Comment: The 23rd has come and gone and I don't see any change.  I still would like to see a proper roadmap or a reply from the powers-that-be. But they don't seem to be up to commenting.